# Passing parameters to Rails 3 template in generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, code-generation, generator

In Rails 2 generators, it's possible to pass data to the [template](http://edgedocs.planetargon.org/classes/Rails/Generator/Commands/Create.html#M002656) in the following manner:

```
record.template(
  "src.html.erb",
  "dest.html.erb",
  :assigns => { :id => id, :name => name }
```

In Rails 3, it looks like [template](http://textmate.rubyforge.org/thor/Thor/Actions.html#template-method) is the new method.  Unfortunately, it looks like the third parameter, `config`, only accepts a `:verbose` option.  Attempting to pass values via `:assigns` doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can pass dynamic value to my Rails 3 template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example of passing parameters to views in Rails 3.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/controller/controller_generator.rb

```
# ...
actions.each do |action|
  @action = action
  @path = File.join(base_path, filename_with_extensions(action))
  template filename_with_extensions(:view), @path
end
```

Template:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/controller/templates/view.html.erb

```
<h1><%= class_name %>#<%= @action %></h1>
<p>Find me in <%= @path %></p>
```

Comment: Nice! Can the actions be passed in at the standard rails  scaffold generation command line?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 templates have access to any methods within the generator, so in your above case, if your generator had a method `name` and a method `id`, you wouldn't have to change anything in your template. Check out the RailsCast for creating generators in Rails 3 at http://railscasts.com/episodes/218-making-generators-in-rails-3.

Comment: Well, I had an `each` loop that had a variable that needed to be passed to the template to generate the same template with multiple names.  What I did to work around this was to define the iterated value in a global scope (via the `@` symbol, not sure what this is called), then created a method in the generator that just returned this value.  This method could be accessed by the template.